# Help chosing between settimeout and setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

UPDATE 2:

OK, looks like it runs the first time after a minute.  How do I get it to run onload, then every minute after that?

**UPDATE 1:**

I've tried: `var interval = setInterval(get_reported_incidents, 60000);` but nothing happens.  in `get_reported_incidents();` I just have an `alert("hello");`.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I want to run a function every minute:

```
get_reported_incidents();
```

But I am not sure which method is best for this task;

`settimeout` or `setinterval`

Comment: please format your code correctly even if it's as little as this. Thanks!

Comment: do you want to run it _on_ the minute, or just "roughly some time each minute" ?

Comment: Roughly would be good enough.  Accuracy is not a concern in this application.

Comment: When you use `setInterval`, it doesn't execute the command right away, it waits until the first interval.

Comment: about update: setInterval does not call your function directly, first need to wait for the timeout to pass which in this case is 1 min. Also it is not good to use alert's there because you might end with multiple alerts waiting in a stack if you fail to close them before the next function call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally personal preference. `setInterval` has some odd edge cases around what happens when the previous interval's code hasn't finished running before the next interval is due to start (not a problem if your interval is every *minute*; intervals every second, which one sometimes wants, get a bit tricky).

I tend to prefer chained `setTimeout` calls (where each schedules the next) because they can't run away with you — your code always has to explicitly say "Okay, and call me back again next time." But properly-written code should work with either.

Chained `setTimeout` calls are also more well-suited to asynchronous operations, like for instance polling something via ajax, because you don't schedule the next timeout until the ajax operation *completes*. Using `setInterval`, because the ajax calls are asynchronous, you could end up overlapping them.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Nothing wrong with your quoted code, except using `alert` is almost always a bad idea if you have any timers going (because `alert` brings the interpreter to a screeching halt).

Comment: the alert is just an example, the actual script in the function is more complex.  It seems that this method does not execute until 60 seconds are up.  So I get a blank screen for a minute, after which I get content.  How do I get content straight away, then update it every minute?

Comment: @oshirowanen: Yes, that's correct: The first "ping" doesn't happen until after the interval. To make one happen right away, just call your function directly just before calling `setInterval`. (Or use the chained `setTimeout` mechanism, which you kick-start by calling your function directly at the outset.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `setinterval` would be the more natural choise. If you use `setTimeout`, you have to start a new timeout from the event handler.

```
window.setInterval(get_reported_incidents, 60*1000);
```

Comment: @oshirowanen: I have tested the code, and it works just fine. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nEAj8/

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` runs a command once after a period of time.  `setInterval` runs a command every time interval.

So, to run `get_reported_incidents` every minute use `setInterval`.

```
var interval = setInterval(get_reported_incidents, 60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout` recursively. See [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts) for more information on why `setInterval` is a poor choice.

```
function timeout (){
    get_reported_incidents();
    setTimeout(timeout, 1000 * 60);
}

timeout(); // start
```

Comment: Wouldn't `setInterval` be a better choice here?

Comment: @rocket and downvoters. Please read [this](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts)

Comment: For repeatable time you should substract the time spent doing `get_reported_incidents`

Comment: I was looking for the link. Dang thing disappeared on me!

Comment: @Josiah: That article talks about `setInterval` calls stacking up, but that's *explicitly* not supposed to happen. If a previous handler is still executing when the next one is scheduled, it's supposed to be skipped. How well implementations do that is another question. (I tend to prefer `setTimeout` as well.)

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Use your firebug or inspector toolbar to debug.

Answer (score 1):

setinterval executes a function at a given interval. settimeout executes a function after a specified wait time, and then exits.

If you are attempting to do a cron-like execution every minute, you will want to use setinterval.

Please see http://javascript.about.com/library/blstvsi.htm for a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, `setInterval()` was designed for repeating events and `setTimeout()` for one-shot events.

However you will tend to find that with `setTimeout()` time will "creep" gradually.  I've not tried this at 1 minute intervals, but with a 1 second timer I found it happened quite a lot.  A clock showing the current time (to the nearest millisecond) would show a steady increase in the millisecond value of "now".

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/LJCJU/ and tweak the interval to see what I mean!

So, for greatest accuracy, I do this:

```
var timerHandler = function() {
    var interval = 60000;
    // do some stuff
    ...

    var now = new Date();
    var delay = interval - (now % interval);
    setTimeout(timerHandler, delay); 
};
```

This is ideal if you want the timer events to be started *in sync* with the clock on your system, rather than at some unspecified time "roughly every minute".

Answer (score 0):

obviously `setinterval` might be easier to maintain in your case

```
get_reported_incidents(); //first call
var interval = setInterval(get_reported_incidents, 60000);
```

vs

```
var interval;
function timeout (){
    get_reported_incidents();
    interval=setTimeout(timeout, 60000);
}
timeout();
```