# Pure Javascript Fading in and fading out not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create fade in and fade out function with JavaScript, but it's not working. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.**I'm not getting transitioning effect**.

```
var fade_in_btn  = document.getElementById('fade-in'),
    fade_out_btn = document.getElementById('fade-out'),
    fading_div   = document.getElementById('fading-div');

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        break;
        }
    }
}

fade_out_btn.onclick = function(){
    for (var i=100; i >= 0; i--) {
        sleep(0010);
        opacity_function(i);
    }
}

fade_in_btn.onclick = function(){
    for (var i=1; i <= 100; i++) {
        sleep(0010);
        opacity_function(i);
    }
}

function opacity_function(opacity_value){
    fading_div.style.opacity = opacity_value / 100;
    fading_div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity_value + ')';
    console.log(fading_div.style.opacity);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27cLv/) with HTML.

All code Working Fine. But from my point of view problem is the for...loop is not updating the value of opacity after each iteration; it's only updating the final value.

Please Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Your Sleep function = BAD Bad bad practice. Use a setTimeout to do the loop.

Comment: i copy/paste from stackoverflow question someone posted it.

Comment: @user3187056 - I found your comment so hilarious I had to up vote it.

Comment: i Just Want to Know How it's Work.

Comment: the way to animate using pure JS is to use requestAnimationFrame. [here](http://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/) is a little tutorial

Comment: if you want to learn pure JS animation without using using requestAnimationFrame, which can be a little confusing at first, change your code to using `setInterval` instead of your sleep function - it's hacky, computationally expensive (always avoid extra `if` statements) and you won't learn much about programming in JS using it

Comment: Using `setTimeout`, as mentioned by epascarello, is better than `setInterval`.

Comment: My Transitioning effect not working.when i click `fade out` and `fade in`.it doesn't show transition effect.it's Just like `visible` and `hidden` property

Comment: "Pure javascript" 2nd tag = jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a pure JS answer that doesn't use `requestAnimationFrame` but i have chosen to discard your sleep function since it is an odd choice and bad practice (and yours doesn't work. also note that there can be no *true* `sleep` in JS.) 
this works:

```
fade_out_btn.onclick = function(){
    var i = 100; 
    var myint = setInterval(function(){
        opacity_function(i);
        i--; 
    if (i<0) clearInterval(myint);
       console.log(i);
    },10); //this is the number of ms between iterations of the codeblock in my setInterval function
}
```

[EDIT: some people were recommending setTimeout. I see no need for that, but in case you really want to use setTimeout, this is how I would do it:

```
var i = 100; 

function fadeout(){
var myint = setTimeout(function(){
    opacity_function(i);
    i--; 
if (i>0) fadeout(); 
},10);
}

fade_out_btn.onclick = fadeout;
```

notice two things: 
1 - I pulled the definition of i outside of the function. you would have to be grabbing that value that you want to decrement from outside the function anyways, because your starting value for a fadeout would presumably not always be 100 but would be set to the current value of the opacity, i.e. the value of `fading_div.style.opacity * 100`. 
2 - i bound a callback to the onclick. 
regarding choosing between `setInterval` and `setTimeout`: 
`setInterval` and `setTimeout` both simply schedule the execution of code. `setInterval` schedules events *every* x ms from when it is executed whereas a series of chained `setTimeout`s schedules an event *in* x ms, then executes again, then schedules another event in x ms. so there is a little bit of time overhead for setTimeout because the real time interval is `x + (the time is takes to execute the codeblock once)`. it is possible have issues with using `setInterval` if the time it takes to execute once is larger than the specified interval but that would not affect such a simple program as yours. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332516/help-chosing-between-settimeout-and-setinterval)
]

Comment: You Know why my code not work for transitioning effect?

Comment: @user3187056 JAvascript's sleep function is intended to "simulate" processor load, but it doesn't. If you look around, the suggestions are to use setTimeout and setInterval instead.

Comment: oh sry i didn't notice. Thanks

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832276/why-there-is-no-sleep-functionality-in-javascript-when-there-is-settimeout-and-s) to understand why there is no sleep function in JS.

Comment: @Dany Please gimme example also with SetTimeout